# Deleting files on remote server

Tags: netbeans, sftp, delete-file

I have a PHP project in NetBeans with remote files (over sftp). When I create, modify anything these changes happening both locally and on my web server. However when I'm trying to delete a file or a folder it gets erased only locally. What could be the problem?

Permissions seems to be ok, all files belong to the user I'm using to access the server.
I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1, default configuration, all updates installed.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans does not have a synchronization function. It is limited to downloading and uploading files. What you can do is to use some external tool, for example WinSCP is capable of synchronizing local and remote directories.

Answer (score 0):

I read what you wrote... but I think it could be a permissions problem.

I also use NetBeans and when I delete a file from the project window it first erase it locally and then syncs with my server.

I login through sftp (using vsftp) as root, which is a bad thing, but you could try this too to be sure if it's a permission issue.

Answer (score -1):

You mistakenly turned off the settings. Please follow these steps:

1. Right click on the project name
2. Select properties
3. From the list of the left select 'Run configuration'
4. On the left almost down, look for the setting 'Upload files:'
5. Make sure you set that to 'On Save'

All the best man

Comment: Sorry for digging this out but please check the next bug report before you use "On save" option... http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202673